# Is there a way to apply SameSite attribute to .AspNetCore.Correlation cookie?

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, cookies, ws-federation, samesite

Following the recent changes in [Chrome 80](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html), it is now required to specify `SameSite=None` on the cookies that needs to be sent across different sites.

I have identified an issue with my Asp.Net Core site when hosted on a frame on a different site. The WS-Federation authentication is currently broken because the `SameSite=None` attribute is missing from the .AspNetCore.Correlation cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Correlation.WsFederation.qG-dtdsIcVBHSRW4SpPpqpMYMrueIrLfWLvElKrbyXg=N; expires=Fri, 17 Jan 2020 09:17:08 GMT; path=/signin-wsfed; secure; httponly
```

I have found a way to add `SameSite=None` to the cookie using the [Cookie Policy Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cookie-policy-middleware):

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
});
```

This works fine, but this causes ALL cookies to be created with this attribute, which I would like to avoid. Would there be a less intrusive solution that could be applied to the correlation cookie only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define the authentication scheme, you can change the settings for the correlation cookie.
E.g.:

```
.AddWsFederation(o =>
{
    o.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Lax;
})
```

**Note from OP**:

> Beware that you need the [.NET Core November 2019 Update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-November-2019/) installed on your server for this to work (else the SameSite attribute isn't issued). See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1#history-and-changes).

Comment: That's what I was looking for. However, when I add this, the FedAuth cookie also gets the SameSite attribute (I used SameSiteMode.None for my needs), which was not really intended.

Comment: Beware that you need the [.NET Core November 2019 Update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-November-2019/) installed on your server for this to work (else the `SameSite` attribute isn't issued). See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1#history-and-changes).

Comment: If you are setting o.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None, which is required for wsfed to work, do not forget to set o.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always, and host the callback handler on https!